# On Invantive Query Tool: the remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required (http://proxy.acme.com:8080/)

Tags: proxy, bluecoat

When installing the Invantive Query Tool I need to configure a license. Version in use is stable-20161021-824. On 'Use free license' I receive the error:

> The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required (http://proxy.acme.com:8080/)

How can I configure the license validation such that the license server URL is accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy credentials used in Internet Explorer seem not to be used using `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` method in Microsoft.NET.

The possibilities are:

- Change the proxy such that the User-Agent 'Invantive' has access to all sites.
- Or whitelist specifically the following:

  - customerservice.invantive.com
  - licenseservice1.invantive.com
  - licenseservice2.invantive.com
  - licenseservice3.invantive.com
  - licenseservice4.invantive.com